# VBA- Attach Email sharepoint attachment link

Tags: excel, sharepoint, outlook, hyperlink, email-attachments

Solution:
Create an automated email from a button within excel spreadsheet to send a sharepoint attachment link.

Problem:
I can generate an outlook email with a excel link but it wont take me to the sharepoint excel and states 'this site cant be reached.'

Current Attachment Code: `.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Path & "xlsb"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method accepts the type of the attachment as the second argument. Can be one of the [OlAttachmentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olattachmenttype) constants.

However, you can try attaching web-based files specifying them as a web attachment in the following way:

```
Set att = aaa.Attachments.Add(newPath, 7)
```

You can't add local files as web attachments. Instead, you must upload the file to OneDrive and then attach a reference to it. Otherwise, your magical `7` value passed as an attachment type parameter will not work.